# Receiving different multicast with same source address on different interfaces

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, multicast

On a system with several network interfaces, I can have the same multicast address and port combination used on different networks, with different data on them. I want to be able to connect to them with several network cards and receive different data on each interface.

To do so, I bind to the interface I want to receive on using the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` option:

```
ip_mreqn mreqn;
memset(&mreqn, 0, sizeof (ip_mreqn));
mreqn.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mc);
mreqn.imr_address.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
mreqn.imr_ifindex = if_nametoindex(device);
if (setsockopt(mct->fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, &mreqn, sizeof(mreqn)) < 0) {
  perror("setsockopt multicast if");
  return 1;
}
```

and make sure the join request is only sent on that interface by setting `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` with the same structure:

```
if (setsockopt(mct->fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreqn, sizeof(mreqn)) < 0) {
  perror("setsockopt add membership");
  return 1;
}
```

While the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` code works (the join request is only sent on the interface specified), the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` does not. Instead once it is able to join the multicast on any of the interfaces, I receive the same data through all sockets, even if they have different `imr_ifindex` set.

Comment: Try it without the IP_MULTICAST_IF step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IP_MULTICAST_IF](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.3) ioctl does not control incoming selection, it is setting the socket's default interface for its outgoing multicast packets.

[IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.4) is the only mechanism for configuring incoming multicast and the memberships it creates are for the entire host, the host does not tailor delivery to individual sockets based on their requested memberships. (You can observe the hosts memberships with `netstat -gn` and the reference count is being used to determine when the host can stop observing, but not which sockets are receiving fan-out. If you have a matching membership from any socket, all sockets that made an applicable `bind(2)` will start receiving that multicast, even if they have never used `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`.)

The usual method to differentiate these packets with out changing the system setup, is to receive them all on a socket using ancillary data to identify their interface. On Linux, this ancillary data setup is done with `IP_PKTINFO` as described in `ip(7)`.

Comment: IP_MULTICAST_IF also controls where IGMP messages are sent. It isn't usual to use both it and a specific `imr_interface` when calling IO_Dd_MEMBERSHIP.

Comment: @EJP, a misunderstanding of IP_MULTICAST_IF seems to be the basis of the incorrect solution in the problem,it is not my suggested solution.

Comment: @lossleader: So if I understand you correctly, I cannot have two sockets listening to the same multicast address but on different addresses, but must have one socket and filter the packages manually? The application where I am running this fires off one thread per data source (= socket), so if I need to share a socket and filter packages that calls for a major rewrite of the packet receiving logic.

Comment: @nafmo yes, if 2 sockets on the same host bind with the same port+(multicast)address they are the same in terms of the logic layer. Every system has its own version of fine grain filtering that applies equally well to multicast as unicast, i.e. you can remap a port via ipchains PREROUTING or perhaps a BPF scoket filter. You can also break a host into separate virtual hosts to get back into general routing problems.. But it sounds like you are trying to emulate SSM, since it would normally be a feature that all but 1 router might drop this multicast if you would be their only subscriber.